# Batch file to search a keyword in all files of a directory

Tags: batch-file

Kindly suggest how can I search a text string which will be input by the user in all files of a directory.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 3):

[findstr](http://thesystemguard.com/TheGuardBook/CCS-Ext/FindStr.htm) is your friend.

For example, to find all files containing Hello:

```
findstr Hello *
```

It also allows subdirectory searches (`/s`) and regular expressions (`/r`) as well.

Of course, you can't achieve *real* power unless you install and use the Cygwin or GnuWin32 tools. [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) if you want an entire UNIX-like environment or [GnuWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages.html) if you just want select tools.

Comment: PowerShell! At least nicer than Cygwin, imho :-)

Comment: Powershell, bah! :-) I already know all the UNIX tools and quite a bit of cmd.exe (where absolutely necessary). I don't want to have to learn yet another tool until it becomes unworkable doing it with Cygwin.

Answer (score 1):

Just use grep. On Windows download GNU grep or other free available grep.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for [FINDSTR](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) ? I am assuming your using windows.