# How to use mget to ftp files containing specific string?

Tags: windows, batch-file, ftp, mget

I am using `mget` to retrieve files from a remote server to local directory in Windows.

```
lcd C:\E920_1\autopkg\saveE1logafterDir\serverlog 
mget /slot/ems2576/appmgr/jdedwards/e920/6210/log/jde_*.log
```

Now, I wish to add additional step to retrieve out of this list, only the files which contains the word "PACKAGE BUILD" inside it.

How do I accomplish it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible. FTP protocol does not have an API to find files by their contents.
See also [Search Within Files On Remote FTP Site](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10065524/850848).

So any implementation you will use will have to download all log files and search their contents locally.

In a batch file, you can use `findstr` command for that:
[Batch file to search a keyword in all files of a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1570938/850848)

---

*You may have a different way of accessing the server files. For example, if you have a (SSH) shell access, you can search the files directly on the server. But that's a completely different topic.*